# Extremely delayed notification of privilege

Tags: support, notifications

I got notified just now (red banner at the top of the page) that I had gained the privilege to vote down and 1 other privilege. Trouble is, vote down requires 125 rep and I passed that point back in October! I don't think I have gained any new privileges since I passed 3000 rep, back in mid-December or so. Maybe this is just a random hiccup. Do others see this happening?

Comment: Maybe this was triggered by the Citizen Patrol badge change (see comment below Yossi's answer)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were some significant changes to the privilege system, so you may have gotten re-notified this once.

Answer (score 3):

I just got a badge for flagging a post ("Citizen Patrol"?), and I didn't do any flagging recently, so there must have been a database glitch that cause it for both of us.

Y.

Comment: From http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange : 2011-02-09: Flagging for moderator attention now counts for the Citizen Patrol badge. This change applies retroactively.

Comment: I got that one and I'm a moderator!  (But I did once flag a question "for moderator attention" as a way of bookmarking it to remember to come back to it to see if it still needed moderation some time afterwards)